# Is it possible to listen to unmount lifecycle of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a generic popup component that gets rendered in several other components in my app.
what I need to do is to run the onclose function inside the popup whenever one of the containers gets destroyed.

So, of course, I can pass this function in a prop in each one of these containers when its unmounting, but my question is - is it possible to do this only from my popup component? meaning put a listener that will do the job whenever one of the containers will unmount?

Comment: "run the onclose function inside the popup whenever one of the containers gets destroyed" when the container unmounts so do the children, just use `componentWillUnmount `?

Comment: No, the only way is to pass callback as a prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do something with the [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API.

Have the following scenario:

```
<YourApp>
  <PopUpController>
    ......... all other components whatever here ..........
  </PopUpController>
</YourApp>
```

The `PopUpController` is a component that initiates a [Context Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) with any helper methods or anything you might want to know about the popups. Methods might be a `show` or a `hide` method like you want.

```
// I'm skipping technicalities because I don't know your exact use cases
const PopUpContext = React.createContext();

function PopUpController({ children }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const openPopUp = () => setOpen(true);

  const closePopUp = () => setOpen(false);

  return (
    <PopUpContext.Provider value={{ openPopUp, closePopUp }}>
      {children}
    </PopUpContext.Provider> 
  );
}
```

In any component on the dismount you can simply import the `PopUpContext` and use it.

```
...
const popUpContext = useContext(PopUpContext);

....
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  // on dismount we call the close
  return () => {
    popUpContext.closePopUp();
  }
}, [popUpContext]);
```